# Find a date in a Table

Tags: vba, excel, date, find

I have a table:

```
Sheet name: 'DateSheet'
Table name: 'DateTable'

| Date       | First Field    | Second Field     | ...
+------------+----------------+------------------+-----
| 2018-01-01 | ...            | ...              | ...
| 2018-01-02 | ...            | ...              | ...
| 2018-01-03 | ...            | ...              | ...
| 2018-01-04 | ...            | ...              | ...
```

The dates are all in `Custom -> YYYY-MM-DD` format.

I want to select the row that corresponds to a specific date. I wrote the following code, yet it does not work:

```
Dim DateTable As Range
Set DateTable = DateSheet.ListObjects("DateTable").Range

Debug.Print Date                            // Returns "2018-05-02", today's date
Debug.Print DateTable.Address               // Returns "$B$5:$P$300", the correct Range address
Debug.Print DateTable.Find("Date").Address  // Returns "$B$5", the correct row
Debug.Print DateTable.Cells(123,1).Value    // Returns "2018-05-02", today's date

// Everything seems to be OK, until now, where I get:
// Err: "Object variable or With block variable not set" :
Debug.Print DateTable.Find(Date).Address    
Debug.Print DateTable.Find(CDate(Date)).Address
Debug.Print DateTable.Find(Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD")).Address
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I have a date with no hidden characters entered with your custom format the following works .Range.Find(Date).Row  I assume that the date you are searching for does appear in the table.

Comment: Consider renaming the Date column (at least to exclude it as a problem)

Comment: Format function converts the date to text, which will not match the date (which is a double)